# float to double conversion changing value

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I have a variable of type float with some value, and there is a point where that value is cast to a double type variable, at that moment the value in the float variable is no more what I see in the double type variable. To make this example easy to follow, I do this in the immediate window to produce whats happening:

```
(double)float.Parse ( "-0.00146256")
```

gives me -0.001462560030631721

the "-0.00146256" (in a string yes) is the origin of this value, and its stored in a float with float.Parse() some where in code, and then at a later point cast to double.

Why is the value changing to a different one in the double variable, and what can I do to prevent this non precision behavior?

Comment: use decimal if you want precision

Comment: __No__. The value of the decimal digits in the string are __not__ stored in the float or double. They are __approximated__! No decimal values except powers of 2 are __storable__ in binary number formats.

Comment: @TaW Yes, integer multiples of (reasonable) powers of 2, to be precise. For example `0.8125` is representable because it is 13 (an integer) times 2**(-4).

Comment: Visit for more detail on decimal, float and double http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net

Comment: its just that if I had done double.Parse at that string to begin with, this problem would not have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

It is how it is suppose to work. Microsoft says

`This type is useful for applications that need large numbers but do not need precise accuracy. If you require very accurate numbers, consider using the Decimal data type.`

You can cast to decimal first and then to double:

```
double d = (double)(decimal)float.Parse("-0.00146256");
```

Comment: why not just `double.Parse("-0.00146256")` or `decimal.Parse("-0.00146256")`?

Comment: Because author wants to get double from float, not from string.

Comment: Oh yeah ... I'm sorry. Should have read the whole question.

Comment: yea I want to but that would change the API inside the app, and a lot of places start giving a lot of errors, so cant do that at this point.